# How can a single thread enter a synchronized block twice before exiting twice?

Tags: java, android, concurrency, synchronization

How can a single thread enter a synchronized block twice before exiting twice?

In my application, I'm implementing a singleton pattern and I'm noticing the logs are showing that a single thread is entering the synchronized block twice, then exiting twice. So, two instances are unhappily created. How is this possible? (I'm particular interested in Java)

```
public class Singleton {
    private static volatile Singleton mSingleton;
    private static final Object mInstanceLock = new Object();
    private Singleton() {
        // Basic initialization.
    }
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (mSingleton == null) {
            log("before synchronized");
            synchronized (mInstanceLock) {
                log("in synchronized start");
                if (mSingleton == null) {
                    mSingleton = new Singleton();
                    log("in synchronized, new Singleton(), " + mSingleton.toString() +
                            " in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() +
                            "-" Thread.currentThread().getId());
                }
                log("in synchronized end");
            }
            log("after synchronized");
        }
        return mSingleton;
    }
}
```

Output, note the different objects created, the constructor is ran through twice (each log in my program actually outputs the current thread id, but I left that out in the above code so that it would look a little neater):

```
before synchronized, in thread id 1
in synchronized start, in thread id 1
before synchronized, in thread id 1
in synchronized start, in thread id 1
// Basic initialization.
in synchronized, new Singleton(), com.example.app.Singleton@42453090 in thread: main-1
in synchronized end, in thread id 1
after synchronized, in thread id 1
// Basic initialization.
in synchronized, new Singleton(), com.example.app.Singleton@424500b0 in thread: main-1
in synchronized end, in thread id 1
after synchronized, in thread id 1
```

In regards to my question, it definitely doesn't seem possible. So, if there isn't an exact answer, then an explanation on what is causing the logs to show the same thread creating two different "singletons" would be great too!

Extra notes, just in case:

- This code is running in an Android app.
- The code is mostly single-threaded, but different threads do use `Singleton`.
- This is repeatable every time I run the code.
- The timestamps of all the "before synchronized" and "in synchronized start" are the same".
- The timestamps of the "in synchronized end" and "after synchronized" pairs are off by about 10ms.
- It's not an April Fools joke lol.
- I'm not sure what other information I can provide, please let me know...

More info from the comments:

- `log()` is just output to the console. A little more specifically, it calls `android.util.Log.d()` in Android, which is the most basic debugging message to console.
- The is only a Java object, with no other inheritance.

Comment: What is `log`? Where is it declared? What does it do?

Comment: We need to see the entire class, particularly the constructor and that `static toString()`. Most likely, you have a recursive call somewhere.

Comment: `log(String)` just calls `Log.d()` in Android, which is just output to the console with nothing else applied. The `toString()` is just the java implementation of `Object.toString()`, which just tells me that the objects are not equal. I'll inspect the code more to see if there any other info I can add.

Comment: Oh, and that `static toString()` is actually a typo in SO only. I'll update that. Thank you.

Comment: what's inside the initializer????

Comment: I agree that a recursive call is likely the culprit for this problem. And, for most questions on SO, this would be over. But, as an interesting turn on things, :), in `Singleton` I have a class member field `private MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum.THING`. Even though that isn't static, since the the Enum is accessed, it is initialized once, which has a `static Singleton` field. Wow. I'll confirm in a bit.

Comment: Awesome! Removing that `static Singleton` field from the Enum that was field in `Singleton` fixed the recursive call! The constructor/initializer didn't have the recursive call, but I'm sure it would have in 95% of the cases. @chrylis, since you were the first to mention a recursive call, I'll accept your answer. ;)

Comment: @Anonsage And finally... if at all possible, just use a single-member enum for something like this.